# Joint probability exercise

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables with the following probability distributions:

[image]

The random variables $S$ and $T$ are defined as:

$$S=X^2+Y^2 \text{ and } T=X+Y$$

(a) Construct the table of the joint probability distribution of $S$ and $T$.

My attempt:

$P(S=0,T=-2)=0, P(S=1,T=-2)=0, P(S=2,T=-2)= P(X=-1 \cap Y=-1)=(0.3)(0.4)=0.12$

$P(S=0,T=-1)=0, P(S=1,T=-1)= P(X=-1\cap Y=0)+P(X=0\cap Y=-1)=0.06+0.16=0.22, P(S=2,T=-1)=0$

$P(S=0,T=0)=P(X=0\cap Y=0)+P(X=1\cap Y=-1)+P(X=-1\cap Y=1)=(0.4)(0.2)=0.08, P(S=1,T=0)=0, P(S=2,T=0)=0$

$P(S=0,T=1)=0, P(S=1,T=1)=P(X=1\cap Y=0)+P(X=0\cap Y=1)=0.06+0.16=0.22, P(S=2,T=1)=0$

$P(S=0,T=2)=0, P(S=1,T=2)=0, P(S=2,T=2)=P(X=1\cap Y=1)=0.12$

---

(b) Calculate the following quantities:

(i) $Var(T)$ , Given that $E(T)=0$

My attempt:

Since $E(T)=0\Rightarrow Var(T)=E(T^2) = E(X^2+Y^2+2XY)$

Now, $E(X^2)=1(0.3)+1(0.3)=0.6, E(Y^2)= 1(0.4)+1(0.4)=0.8, E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)=0(0)$

So, $E(T^2)=0.6+0.8=1.4$

(ii) Calculate $Cov(S,T)$:

My attempt:

$Cov(S,T)=Cov(X^2+Y^2,X+Y)=Cov(X^2,X)+Cov(X^2,Y)+Cov(Y^2,X)+Cov(Y^2,Y)= Cov(X^2,X)+Cov(Y^2,Y)=E(X^3)-E(X^2)E(X)+E(Y^3)-E(Y^2)E(Y)=\bigl(-0.3+0.3\bigr)-0.6(0)+\bigl(-0.4+0.4\bigr)-0=0$

(iii) Calculate $E(S|T=0)=0$ Since as I calculate above, the only joint probability between $S$ and $T$ that is not $0$ given $T=0$ is $P(S=0,T=0)=0.08$ and this means that the expectation is $(0.08)(0)=0$

---

(c) Are $S$ and $T$ uncorrelated? My answer: Yes, since the correlation is equal to $0$

---

(d) Are  $S$ and $T$ independent?

My answer;

No, since $P(S=0)=0.08$, $P(T=0)=P(X=1\cap Y=-1)+P(X=-1 \cap Y=1)+P(X=0\cap Y=0)=0.08=0.31$, and $P(S=0,T=0)\neq P(S=0)P(T=0)$

**Is all of this correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve the problem is to do a tabular representation of your data

here is the first table I did

[image]

Now all you have to do is to copy these probability mumber in a 2-way table getting the joint distribution ${S;T}$ (summing the probability of the same outcome, obviously)

This is the result

[image]

Without any calculations, it is self evident that $S$ and $T$ ARE NOT independent; this is an immediate consequence of the fact that there are some empty cells in the joint distribution. The rest of request are also quite immediate using the table above. When you have the joint distribution you have immediately any answer.